# Replication issue in LuaTeX question

Tags: luatex

When I view other peoples questions/answers, I typically run it myself just to see if I end up with their issue/solution. When I ran the code in [this question by @Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205615/273733), my LuaTeX wouldn't compile with this error message:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022)
restricted system commands enabled.
(./unttled-1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \pdfprotrudechars
                   =2
?
```

Why is this? Has this command, `\pdfprotrudechars`, been depreciated? The question is nearly 9 years old so I am sure much has changed. The code from the question:

```
\pdfprotrudechars=2

\rpcode\font 50 = 200
\efcode\font 50 = 333

\directlua{

local function FMItable (name,t)
    print ("---- looking at table ", name, tostring(t))
      for k, v in pairs(t) do
    print("    ", k,"=", tostring(v))
      end
    print("----------------")
end

 FMItable("char 50",font.fonts[font.current()].characters[50])

}
\bye
```

I am just curious as to why my running of the code failed, I searched for this command but couldn't see anything about it being depreciated from a Google/TeX.SE search. Most of those questions on `\pdfprotrudechars` involve XeLaTeX however and I do not typically use TeX although it does intrigue me, mainly LaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: 2014 is using a beta release of luatex, any luatex answers from that era need "care" to be interpreted

Comment: `\protudechars` in luatex after 0.85

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the answer, this confused me! I would be happy to accept an answer if that was okay with you and you put that in an answer, makes sense. I didn't know that at all, sorry for that.

Comment: Not quite sure if it's appropriate to call the 2014 version of LuaTeX "beta". For sure, its version number was still below `1.0`.

Comment: @Mico look at the log file in Frank's answer:-)  `This is LuaTeX, Version` **beta** `-0.79.1 `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Excellent point! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That dates from 2014 so is using a beta release of luatex, any luatex answers from that era need "care" to be interpreted.

It is `\protudechars` in luatex after 0.85